# grpc build is stopped in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, grpc

enviornment

- aws ec2 instance ubuntu 22

Run

```
$ cd grpc
$ mkdir -p cmake/build
$ pushd cmake/build
$ cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON \
      -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MY_INSTALL_DIR \
      ../..
$ make -j 4
```

Result

```
[ 42%] Built target flags
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target grpc_unsecure
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/grpc_unsecure.dir/src/core/ext/filters/channel_idle/channel_idle_filter.cc.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_channelz.cc.o
[ 42%] Linking CXX static library libprotoc.a
[ 45%] Built target libprotoc
[ 45%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/flags/CMakeFiles/flags_usage_internal.dir/internal/usage.cc.o
In file included from /home/ubuntu/.local/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/channel_idle/channel_idle_filter.cc:43:
/home/ubuntu/.local/grpc/src/core/lib/promise/loop.h:121:31: warning: attribute ignored in declaration of ‘union grpc_core::promise_detail::Loop<F>::<unnamed>’ [-Wattributes]
  121 |   GPR_NO_UNIQUE_ADDRESS union { GPR_NO_UNIQUE_ADDRESS PromiseType promise_; };
      |                               ^
/home/ubuntu/.local/grpc/src/core/lib/promise/loop.h:121:31: note: attribute for ‘union grpc_core::promise_detail::Loop<F>::<unnamed>’ must follow the ‘union’ keyword
[ 45%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_factory.cc.o
[ 45%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_flags_usage_internal.a
[ 45%] Built target flags_usage_internal
[ 45%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/grpc_plugin_support.dir/src/compiler/cpp_generator.cc.o
```

Build is stopped at the line above

why build stop??

after instance reboot, retry also fail

Comment: If your grpc version is up-to-date, I'd recommend filing an issue in the repo at github.com/grpc/grpc